# How to create an animation from several .obj files in maya?

Tags: animation, 3d-meshes, maya

I have several .obj files. I plan to create an animation from these .obj file. Every mesh in one .obj file is correspond to one frame. And every frame only show one .obj file (meshes in others .obj files are hidden).I use Maya.

Any body has any suggestions?

Comment: Erm, don't? That's what we have skeletal animation for generally, way faster and way more features. If you want to do it then you might need to create a maya exporter cause this is unlikely to be a supported use case.

Comment: Try using keyframes and interpolating between those values!

Comment: @KevinvanderVelden He's not saying he wants to export an animation as multiple files, he has each frame as a separate mesh as _input_ and wants to convert this to a single, animated mesh. This is a reasonable questions.

Answer (score -1):

Just now I got a solution from here:[Autodesk Maya Tool - OBJ Sequence Import/Export demo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fl2NplM1ih4).

This video show a tutorial for importing OBJ Sequences. After importing the obj sequences, I just got an animation composed of the imported obj sequences. Then I could export the animation to a .avi file

Download the script used in the tutorial from:[OBJ Sequences Import/Export 2.0.3 (maya script)](http://creativecrash.com/maya/downloads/scripts-plugins/data-management/c/obj-sequences-import-export).

Thanks.